# Display List values using repeater control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, repeater

I've added the content from `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` to a `List<string>`. Now I wish to display each row from the list using the Repeater control. 
I've done this before with the `<%# Eval("Name") %>` when I got the data directly from `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`.

But now when they're in a list, the "Name" attribute does not seem to be there anymore. So how should I do this with the Eval..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the Data is the string itself. Get it using this code.

```
<%#GetNane(Container.DataItem)%>
```

and on code behind

```
public string GetNane(object oItem)
{
  return (string)oItem;
}
```

Comment: and place the List<string> as data to the repeater.